# Is Axis2/C still being maintained?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, axis, axis2c

I have to write a web-service client and server (a kind of proxy) and was looking at my options.  I narrowed it down to Axis2/C and gSOAP for a number of reasons.  I tended toward Axis2/C mainly because of the more permissive license, but saw that the last version is dated April 2009!

Is it still being maintained?  Has everyone gone to something else (gSOAP or something else entirely)?

PS: I have no experience in WS and got all my info from Google searches.

Comment: Wow, I can't even download Axis2/C from Apache.  I guess that answers my question: it's dead!

Answer (score 0):

Axis2/C is still maintained but progress is too slow, it has only few commits in last year.

Consider using of [Axis2/C-unofficial](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/) project which is a fork of Axis2/C-1.6.0.

For details please see [this answer](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/).

Comment: Thanks, but I'll probably stay clear of Axis, I need long term maintainability.