# How to build axis2c Unofficial source code

Tags: c, soap, axis2c

I have to create SOAP services in C using [axis2C](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/). But since axis2C is kind of not maintained properly as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865665/is-axis2-c-still-being-maintained), I have to use [axis2C unofficial](https://code.google.com/archive/p/axis2c-unofficial/) source code. But I could not see configure file to build the sources. How should I build this. I checked all the documentation both in [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/axis2c-unofficial/) and in the [github repo](https://github.com/loentar/axis2c-unofficial) but no luck. All points to the axis2C official documentation. Should I copy the sources from unofficial to official code and try with the configure script in official folder ?

Comment: Is there a `configure.ac`? Then install `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` and try the command `autoreconf -i`

Comment: Thanks @FelixPalmen it did the trick. Also I found one autogen.sh script in source as per this [wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/axis2c-unofficial/wikis/InstallationManualLinux.wiki). Could you please post this as answer ?

Comment: Glad it helped. I wrote an answer hopefully explaining enough to be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project probably uses the [GNU build system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System). In this system, `./configure` is a portable shell script that is automatically generated from hand-written input files, the main file is `configure.ac`.

So, distribution packages of the source will contain `./configure`, therefore enabling anyone on any platform with a `sh`-compatible shell and a `make` utility to build the software. But as it is a *generated* file, you will not find it in source-code repositories, e.g. on github.

To build a package using the GNU build system directly from source controls, you have to use the *GNU autotools* yourself to generate `./configure`. In order to do this, install the following packages:

- `autoconf` -- generates `./configure` from `./configure.ac`.
- `automake` -- generates portable makefile templates `Makefile.in` from `Makefile.am` (those templates are then filled with values by the `./configure` script to write the final `Makefile`s)
- `libtool` -- tools for building dynamic shared objects on different platforms

Then, the command `autoreconf -i` given in the root of your source package should generate the `./configure` script for you.

Note that there are packages providing a script `./autogen.sh` (or similarly named). If this is there, you should call it instead of running `autoreconf -i` yourself, it might contain additional necessary preparation steps. `./autogen.sh` will typically directly run the generated `./configure` for you.